# Update column in table based on value of list

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a student table, and I want to update the student score column depending on a list of students' scores.

student_list = db.session.query(Student).filter(Student.id == id)

student_score = [90,89,70]

```
for i,d in enumerate(student_list):
   d['score']=student_score[i]
```

it gives me this error:
TypeError: 'Student' object does not support item assignment.

Comment: You probably want `d.score = ...`

Comment: thanks, @snakecharmerb but it didn't work, I think the issue here is the type of  studint_list is flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery

Comment: Iterating over the query will yield `Student` instances.

Comment: you can try .all()